# How to make a FBSession with Facebook oauth token?

Tags: ios, facebook, social-framework

I have used the social framework to login Facebook and got successfully the token. Do you know how to set it to the `FBsession` in Facebook `SDK`? I want to make a session with this token, then set it to `FBSession.activeSession`, so everything is synchronize :).
Thanks guys.

```
ACAccountType *facebookAccountType = [self.accountStore accountTypeWithAccountTypeIdentifier:ACAccountTypeIdentifierFacebook];

NSDictionary *options = @{
@"ACFacebookAppIdKey" : @"123456789",
@"ACFacebookPermissionsKey" : @[@"publish_stream"],
@"ACFacebookAudienceKey" : ACFacebookAudienceEveryone}; // Needed only when write permissions are requested

[self.accountStore requestAccessToAccountsWithType:facebookAccountType options:options 
                             completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error) {
                                 if (granted)
                                 {
                                     NSArray *accounts = [self.accountStore
                                                          accountsWithAccountType:facebookAccountType];
                                     self.facebookAccount = [accounts lastObject];
                                     ACAccountCredential *facebookCredential = [facebookAccount credential];
                                    NSString *accessToken = [facebookCredential oauthToken];

                                 } else {
                                     NSLog(@"%@",error);
                                     // Fail gracefully...
                                 }
                             }];
```

Comment: If you're going to use the Facebook SDK, why not just use it to log in, instead of using the social framework? The social framework only gives you access to users who have connected their accounts with iOS, whereas the SDK gives you access to all Facebook users.

Comment: FB SDK has to switch app for authentication. I want to limit this as least as impossoble.